# what does "This subjective world, interpreted in a particular way, is for us the “objective” world" means?

Tags: punctuation, reading

Modern psychological theory states that the process of understanding is a matter of construction, not reproduction, which means that the process of understanding takes the form of the interpretation of data coming from the outside and generated by our mind. For example, the perception of a moving object as a car is based on an interpretation of incoming data within the framework of our knowledge of the world. While the interpretation of simple objects is usually an uncontrolled process, the interpretation of more complex phenomena, such as interpersonal situations, usually requires active attention and thought.
Psychological studies indicate that it is knowledge possessed by the individual that determines which stimuli become the focus of that individual’s attention, what significance he or she assigns to these stimuli, and how they are combined into a larger whole. **This subjective world, interpreted in a particular way, is for us the “objective” world**; we cannot know any world other than the one we know as a result of our own interpretations.

Question) what does "this subjective world, interpreted in a particular way, is for us the “objective” world" means?

My opinion)
I know that the word "objective" means "based on real facts and not influenced by personal beliefs or feelings". So, I guess the author indicates that the subjective world is the one where we interpret all the things coming from outside, and the "objective" world is the one where we know the things only from our interpretations and we don't know the others.

Comment: @Iloveeverybody please stick to English

Comment: @JavaLatte Sorry…

Comment: @Michael Harvey Sorry…

Comment: @Iloveeverybody - you are forgiven.

Comment: Why the downvote? This core of this question is the use of double-quotes, which don't exist in the writing of the OP's language. I think it's a useful question.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the word **"objective"** is in quotes. This indicates that it's not really objective. Some people call these [scare quotes](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/single-quotation-marks-versus-double-quotation-marks).

We experience everything in a subjective way. But we cannot experience it any other way, so to us it appears to be objective. It is "objective".

Comment: I think it’s weird at first. How is the antonym used as an apposition. It’s called scare quotes!